# Do indexed db do parallel processing?

Tags: indexeddb

In my indexed db code in IE11 and chrome, I have a function like this to manage cache. But what I do is, I issue a bunch of delete commands on expired keys (**could be multiple**) on the cache, and then I issue read commands to read stuff (**could also be multiple**) from the cache. The delete and read are both asynchronous. The commands are issues synchronously one after each other like delete, delete, delete, ..., then read, read, read, ... I don't chain anything in the callbacks of anything.

What I want is that, if I delete a key called `A`, and then read a key called `A` (this is not in the callback of the delete command, just synchronously after), the value I read should always be null or undefined.

Is it possible the read command could read something before the delete command takes place for the same key because of the nature of asynchronous programming? Or do they do some sort of single processing queue system where all the tasks are done 1 at a time so this ensures deletes happen before any reads?

```
    function deleteExpiredItems(callback) {
        console.info("Clearing expired items now.");

        dbEnumerator(function(key, value, expired) {
            if (expired) {
                console.warn("Key " + key + " expired and is being deleted because it expired.");
                remove(key);
            }
        }, callback);
    }

    function dbEnumerator(itemProcessor, callback) {
        if (db) {
            var transaction = db.transaction([store_NAME], IDBTransaction_READ_ONLY); 
            var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(store_NAME);
            var cursorRequest = objectStore.openCursor();

            cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
                if (event.target.result) {
                    var val = event.target.result.value.value;
                    var key = event.target.result.value.id;
                    var expired = isCacheExpired(val[1], val[2]);
                    itemProcessor(key, val, expired);
                    event.target.result['continue']();
                }
            };

            transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
                callback(event);
            };
        } else {
            console.warn("Cannot enumerate on database when it is not set.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Within a transaction, requests are always processed in the order they are made.

```
var tx = db.transaction('my_store', 'readwrite');
var store = tx.objectStore('my_store');

var r1 = store.delete(key);
r1.onsuccess = e => console.log('deleted');

var r2 = store.get(key);
r2.onsuccess = e => console.log('got: ' + r2.result);
```

The delete request was made first, and will execute first. So the get request will always result in undefined.

Comment: how about multiple transactions? are they in sequential order or parallel?

Comment: Transactions can start when they can grab a shared (read-only) or exclusive (read/write) over the set of object stores they need access to (their scope).